# How to make PDF in my server show instead of downloading

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

I uploaded a PDF File in my Web.

But the PDF file while accessed via a URL, is getting downloaded instead of showing it in the web browser.

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

- If you are generating PDF file from javascription then you should make sure you are representing your PDF file as `datauri` base 64 encoded data.
- If your file is on server then make sure server headers sent back contains `Content-Disposition: inline; filename='example.pdf'` so it will tell to display inline rather than download it